# Parent checkbox inputs are checked when thei children inputs becomes checked. iCheck Plugin

Tags: jquery, html

I am using the [iCheck Plugin](https://github.com/fronteed/icheck/tree/2.x) to style my checkboxes on my website.

I have multiple parents categories and then their subcategories (children) in which my website's users can select from. My goal is to have all of the parent categories in a disabled state by default and then have them become checked (but stay disabled to user click) if any of their children categories are checked. For more clarity: Parent categories always needs to be checked if any of it's subcategories are checked, and I can't depend on my users to do this, which is why I'm looking to automate it.

Here is the simplified HTML layout...

```
<li class="categories">

    //Parent that is disabled and needs to get into a disabled-checked state
    <label class="selectit icheck-label">
        <div class="icheckbox_polaris icheck-item">
            <input type="checkbox" name="field_1" value="79" class="icheck-input title-input">
        </div>
    Parent 1
    </label>

  //ul that holds all children categories
  <ul class="children">
      <li>
      <label class="selectit icheck-label">
          <div class="icheckbox_polaris icheck-item">
              <input type="checkbox" name="fields_2" value="97" class="icheck-input">
          </div> 
       Child 1
      </label>
      </li>

      <li>
      <label class="selectit icheck-label">
          <div class="icheckbox_polaris icheck-item">
              <input type="checkbox" name="fields_2" value="97" class="icheck-input">
          </div> 
       Child 2
      </label>
      </li>
  </ul>

</li>
```

**Here is where I'm at so far with the jQuery code...**

**Step 1**

```
jQuery('.categories').find('input:first').addClass('title-input');
```

This finds the first `<input>` which is the parent input of each category list and adds the class `.title-input` to it.

**Step 2**

```
jQuery('.title-input').icheck('disabled');
```

This finds the newly added `.title-input` class on the parent input and puts it into a disabled state (can't be clicked by users). This works.

**Step 3** (Need help here)

```
jQuery('.children input').on('ifChecked', function(event) {

    console.log("Hello!"); //this log works

    jQuery('.title-input').icheck('checked');

});
```

So my problem here is that **all** of the parent inputs become checked when any child input in any category is clicked. And when the child input is unchecked, the parents don't become unchecked again (they should). I'm just learning jQuery and this so far is out of my element. iCheck the plugin has multiple aids that would help accomplish this if you visit the page I linked to above, but I just can't figure it out.

Also if you're wondering why I'm not using shorthand jQuery, it's because I'm doing this on Wordpress.

Thanks you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery('.children input').on('ifChecked', function(event) {
    jQuery(this).closest('.categories').find('.title-input').icheck('checked');
});

jQuery('.children input').on('ifUnchecked', function(event) {
    var category = jQuery(this).closest('.categories');
    if (category.find(".children input:checked").length === 0) {
        category.find('.title-input').icheck('unchecked');
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:** To ensure that parent checkboxes are included in your form submission:

```
jQuery('#idOfYourForm').on('submit', function() {
    jQuery('.title-input').icheck('enable');
    return true; // needed to allow form submission to happen
});
```

Comment: Hey phari, this is great and it works. I was really hoping that the value of the checkbox in a **Checked & Disabled** state would still post the value as checked because [icheck allows a simultaneous checked and disabled state](http://fronteed.com/iCheck/), but it didn't. So I ended up setting the parent checkbox to `display: none;` and keeping it enabled while using pieces of your jQuery code. If there's something I missed about why the value wasn't registered in the Checked & Disabled state, please let me know. Feels odd that they even offer it if it doesn't even work. Thanks for you help.

Comment: BTW, bounty will be awarded in 16 or so hours as Stackoverflow puts a timer on it.

Comment: Disabled inputs are not included when their containing forms are submitted, that's by spec.  You can get around this by adding an onsubmit handler to the form that re-enables the parent checkboxes.

Comment: Adding the re-enable on the checkbox wouldn't work because I don't want the user to be able to click it themselves. I want to prevent user error while still showing the user which parent their child selection falls under. The `display: none;` isn't as fancy but it will have to do. Still find it strange that the icheck plugin includes a greyed out and checkmarked button but doesn't allow it to pass the checked value... a bit misleading.

Comment: If you re-enable the parent checkboxes during onsubmit, the user won't have any opportunity to click them, because a new page will load.  Or, if you're submitting via AJAX, onsubmit should enable, send, then re-disable.  (Regarding disabled inputs not being submitted, that's a defined behavior of HTML forms, not specific to iCheck.)

Comment: That might be a way this could work. It's not being submitted using ajax. Any way you could adjust your answer to include the necessary code for that? I haven't got that far into jQuery yet. Would really appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like...

`jQuery(this).closest(".children").prev().find(".title_input").icheck("checked");`

?

That is, when your input is checked (this), find it's containing `.children` container - then from there find the previous sibling (the `<label>`) and within that, find the `.title-input` element and "check" it.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the containing `.categories` - the answer from @phari does the same thing, but cleaner!

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery('.title-input')` gets all objects with class 'title-input', not just the parent of the child clicked.

`this` used within the `'.on('ifChecked', ...)` block will be the element clicked; try using that to retrieve the parent just for that child.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery('.title-input')` gets all the parent categories, which is why it's checking all of them.  Instead, use the checkbox associated to the event and get the closest parent category by traversing the tree.  It would look something like this.

```
jQuery('.children input').on('ifChecked', function(event) {
    console.log("Hello!"); //this log works
    jQuery(this).closest('.categories').find('.title-input').icheck('checked');
});
```